# Integrate Uber with my app

Tags: ios, uber-api

I have tried to make uber button when you click the button all I want is open uber app with dropoff Location.

I already read there api (https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk) and I did exactly what it says but when I press uber button all what it does is open uber app without any dropoff Location.

That's my code please guide me where

```
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:26.410640 longitude:50.099568];

UBSDKRideRequestButton *button = [[UBSDKRideRequestButton alloc] init];
UBSDKRidesClient *ridesClient = [[UBSDKRidesClient alloc] init];
CLLocation *pickupLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude: self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
CLLocation *dropoffLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: loc.coordinate.latitude longitude: loc.coordinate.longitude];
__block UBSDKRideParametersBuilder *builder = [[UBSDKRideParametersBuilder alloc] init];
builder = [builder setPickupLocation: pickupLocation];
builder = [builder setDropoffLocation: dropoffLocation];
[ridesClient fetchCheapestProductWithPickupLocation: dropoffLocation completion:^(UBSDKUberProduct* _Nullable product, UBSDKResponse* _Nullable response) {
    if (product) {
        builder = [builder setProductID: product.productID];
        button.rideParameters = [builder build];
        [button loadRideInformation];
    }
}];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: This might not be the cause, but it looks like you mixed up the dropoffLocation with the pickupLocation @ ``fetchCheapestProductWithPickupLocation``. The time and price estimates on the button should be incorrect due to the location mix-up.

Comment: No sir that's coming directory from there developer site

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the `RideRequestButton` uses deep links to send the parameters to the Uber app. As mentioned on the [very button of the README section](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/#adding-parameters-with-rideparameters), you must provide a nickname or formatted address for that location. Otherwise, the pin will not display.

I updated your code to accomplish that. Would you give it a try and let me know if that works?

```
CLLocation *dropoffLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:26.410640 longitude:50.099568];

UBSDKRideRequestButton *button = [[UBSDKRideRequestButton alloc] init];
UBSDKRidesClient *ridesClient = [[UBSDKRidesClient alloc] init];
CLLocation *pickupLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude: self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
__block UBSDKRideParametersBuilder *builder = [[UBSDKRideParametersBuilder alloc] init];
builder = [builder setPickupLocation: pickupLocation];
[[builder setPickupLocation:pickupLocation] 
builder = [builder setDropoffLocation: dropoffLocation nickname: @"Somewhere" address:@"123 Fake St."];
[ridesClient fetchCheapestProductWithPickupLocation: pickupLocation completion:^(UBSDKUberProduct* _Nullable product, UBSDKResponse* _Nullable response) {
    if (product) {
        builder = [builder setProductID: product.productID];
        button.rideParameters = [builder build];
        [button loadRideInformation];
    }
}];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Could you please mark this thread as solved if your issue is solved? Thx!

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, Uber app still open without dropoff location.

Comment: Are you sure that the fetchCheapestProductWithPickupLocation is successful? If it isn't, then you never set the ride parameters. I would suggest setting the ride parameters before making that call and then updating them to include the product ID when it returns.